Empty Request Body in Microsoft Power Automate from Datadog Notifications
I have created synthetic tests in Datadog and set up notifications to trigger workflows in Microsoft Power Automate. However, I am encountering an issue where the request body in Power Automate is consistently empty.
The request body received by your Power Automate workflow is empty, preventing the workflow from functioning correctly.
What I have found right now is that Datadog notification request includes the header "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked". This signifies that the request body is being sent in fragmented chunks for efficiency. Unfortunately, Microsoft Power Automate's initial trigger, specifically designed for the first interaction, might not be equipped to handle this chunked format effectively.
enter image description here
enter image description here
I cannot edit the datadog sent request header but I tried the same header in postman without transfer encoding key and I received the notification with request body.
